# How can I convert paragraphs in this text file into a single line? (not the entire file, but each paragraph should be a separate line)

Tags: python

[Link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHtD8.png)(This is the approach that I tried)

```
with open(directory) as f: # Loop to parse through each FASTA file
line = f.readline()
while line:
    line= f.readline()
    data = line.split('\n\n')
    data = [line.replace('\n', ' ') for line in data]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And please [do not upload images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875). Copy-paste the text instead.

Answer (score -1):

You have to open the file (lets say "fasta.txt"), not the directory. I suggest you to adapt your solution this way:

```py
with open("fasta.txt") as f:
    content = f.read().split("\n\n")
    data = [seq.replace("\n", "") for seq in content]
```